Dart Console Application Not Printing Input Value
I am trying to read a string input from the console in a Dart application and print it. However, after entering the input, the output does not appear in the console. Here is my code:
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String name = stdin.readLineSync()!; // input as `neel`
  print(name);
}

When I run this code and input 'neel', nothing is printed to the console. How can I resolve this issue?
I am using Dart's stdin.readLineSync() to read input from the console. My expectation is that after entering 'neel' and pressing Enter, the program should print 'neel' to the console. However, this does not happen, and I receive no output.

I have checked the Dart documentation for stdin.readLineSync() and verified that my usage seems correct.
I tried adding a flush to the stdout to ensure that the output buffer is cleared, but this did not resolve the issue.
I ran the code in different environments (VS Code terminal, IntelliJ, and standard command line) but faced the same problem in each case.

Could someone help me understand why the input is not being printed and how to fix this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

That code should work fine

yes!, you're right!, i know but when i give input as neel then not display the output as neel.

There isn't anything wrong with your code (other than unconditionally assuming that stdin.readLineSync() doesn't return null), and I can't reproduce your problem.  If this is reproducible on your system, then there is something wrong with your system.
